# How to differentiate between actual community ads posts (for voting on the ads) and discussion about them?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, advertising, moderator-tags

We've had some discussion on Super User lately pertaining to what the focus and scope of [Community Promotion Ads](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) should be.

There are two categories of posts pertaining to community ads:

- Those in which we actually *select* the advertisements to be shown
- Those in which we *discuss* the issues surrounding community ads

The tag [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) has been applied to both, but it is a special tag: it is required for the ads to show up on the main site, and will pre-populate the answer field with the template for community ads:

```
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

  [1]: http://image-url
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Obviously, this doesn't need to - and should not - occur for meta posts *discussing* community ads; it only needs to be there for meta posts which *contain* the ads. Users keep adding the tag though when discussing community ads, because of this ambiguity. We have been changing this to the [advertising](/questions/tagged/advertising) tag on discussion questions, which does not introduce the template code.

Is this the appropriate way to be tagging these? Is there a more appropriate tag for the discussion questions? If  [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) really should only be used for posts for suggesting ads, then I propose that it be made into a moderator restricted tag like [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) and [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), so that users cannot apply it willy-nilly. If it should be used for discussion, then the template should not be automatically applied except on specifically designated posts.

Comment: I'm torn between wanting to submit an edit to make the tags show up properly, or leaving it as is because them not showing as mod-only tags kinda reflects the reason this question was asked to begin with.

Comment: @GraceNote I think you've stumbled upon a weird bug... if you look at the revision history you can see that they are in fact `meta-tag`... I'm not sure why they display properly in the revision history but not in the rendered post.

Comment: Huh, I noticed that it rendered in the preview but I didn't check the revision history, so I assumed it was just a matter of the saved copy not being updated with the tag's status and the dynamically generated preview matching properly, but now I'm not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have made community-ads a moderator only tag on all sites.  This will be pushed out during the next build.

[advertising](/questions/tagged/advertising) is the correct tag to use for questions related to advertising, but *not* the actual ads.